# Convert Wavefront to Prometheus query

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to convert Wavefront to Prometheus query.

```
rawcount(lowpass(1, ts(kube_node_status_condition, condition=Ready and status=true and test_monitoring_name=testDC))) / rawcount(lowpass(1, ts(kube_node_status_condition, condition=Ready and (status=true or status=false) and test_monitoring_name=testDC))) * 100 > 5
```

Above query to get "Nodes Not Ready: > 5%" in Wavefront but I want same query in Prometheus. Could someone please help here?

I had tried to convert it in to Promethues as below but no luck

```
sum(up == 1 and kube_node_status_condition{condition="Ready", status="true", test_monitoring_name="testDC"}) / sum(up == 1 and kube_node_status_condition{condition="Ready", status=“true” or status=“false”, test_monitoring_name="testDC"}) * 100 > 5
```